# Recording ZipLine Sounds (Any Advice)

Tags: sound-design, sound, sound-effects-recording, field-recording

I'm looking specifically, to create the sound you hear when swat/military zipline down a buildings or from aircraft (10 seconds in length or so)

What are some ways to emulate this, any ideas? I've tried objects running across cloth, results weren't very good.

thanks in advance

Comment: I got a decent sound like this from a thick steel double bass string. That won't work for 10 seconds, but I'd be keeping an eye out for steel cables - maybe a winch or similar.

Comment: Fingernail [or less painfully] steel nail-file dragged over coarse nylon sheeting [think tent or even coarser] ?